# Grails Class with hasMany

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I have this domain class that has a one-to-many relationship as with dynamic scaffolding show below:

**Domain:**

```
package mienapp

class Announcements {
    String user
    String title
    String comments
    Date dateCreated


    static hasMany = [tag: Tags]

    static mapping = {  
       comments sqlType: 'text'
    }

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
package mienapp
class AnnouncementsController {
  def scaffold = true
  def index() { 
     redirect(action: list)
  }
}
```

When controller redirects to list, the table shows all fields defined in announcements class. How can I show the value of field from tags in the table as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your list method returns a model with an Announcements instance as

```
def list() {
  ..    
  [announcementsInstance: announcementsInstance, ...]
}
```

in your view, you can access tags like so

```
<g:each in="${announcementsInstance.tag}" var="tag">
  ${tag.someproperty}
</g:each>
```